# Перевод + (возможно) баг

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В проверках во вкладке "Статистика" со знаками какая-то беда.
Если знаки достигнуты, то они дублируются,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

иначе они не отображаются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также нет перевода для кнопки.
P.S. При создании этого вопроса было замечено окно, которое также требует перевода.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавил перевод ["Начать проверку"](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14812).

Со знаками у меня сейчас нормально отображается. Вероятно, баг пофиксили, т.к. в вашем случае отображались по сути отрицательные значения.

> [image: Прогресс в получении знаков]

По баннеру добавил переводы:

- [Предоставьте подробности и какие-либо исследования](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14279)
- [Теперь вы готовы задать ваш первый вопрос и сообщество готово вам помочь! Чтобы получить лучшие ответы, взгляните на рекомендации:](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14276)
- [При необходимости опишите, что вы пытались сделать](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14285)