# Отсутвует перевод в предлагаемых правках "Start reviewing now"

Tags: дефект, локализация, правки

Отсутвует перевод в предлагаемых правках (вкладка "Статистика") `Start reviewing now`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перевод + (возможно) баг](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10490/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b3)